# How to make a USB BOOTABLE for windows 7 from linux ubuntu?

Tags: boot, windows, rufus

I need make a usb bootable for windows 7 for GPT partition and UEFI, mi desktop computer loss the boot file and now i need fix it... someone know a good software highly configurable for this that work on linux ubuntu?.

Comment: This question is [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: oh! sorry i don't write that is on linux ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can Use WoeUSB

Installing commands are as follows -

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8

$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install woeusb
```